# Request.QueryString usage to read passed url

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I use code Request.QueryString["u"] to read passed URL to my web application. Everything works fine if passed url do not has parameters but for example if such url is submitted

http://mywebapp:80/submit.aspx?u=http://www.submitedurl.com/top_sellers_pdf.php?GoodThru=7-21-2011&comments=This+is+a+test+for+PDF

the Request.QueryString["u"] return

http://www.submitedurl.com/top_sellers_pdf.php?GoodThru=7-21-2011

and comments=This+is+a+test+for+PDF is ignored.

I understand why this happens no need to explain :), but how this could be solved?

One solution I think would be to surround parameter with quotes. Like this

http://mywebapp:80/submit.aspx?u="http://www.submitedurl.com/top_sellers_pdf.php?GoodThru=7-21-2011&comments=This+is+a+test+for+PDF"

What other solution could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your querystring, use:

```
var value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("My querystring with & inside it");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is passing that URL to your application is doing it wrong.  RFC 2396 states that `&` is a reserved character in URIs, and must be escaped to `%26` if it is to be treated as data, and not a query string separator.  Is it possible to fix the behaviour of whatever is passing the URLs to your web application?

Failing that, you'll need to grab the query string and parse it yourself.  You can get the whole query string as one string using:

```
Request.QueryString.ToString()
```

... and get everything after the 'u=' argument using:

```
Request.QueryString.ToString().Substring(Request.QueryString.ToString().IndexOf("u=")+2)
```

Comment: But what if the original url contains parameters that contain & (%26) as data?

Comment: The `&`s should be escaped in the query string to `%26`.  The `%`s should be escaped in the query string to `%25`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the URL parameter, you can replace the & with something else when the url is generated, and replace it back when you extract it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the raw url and parse it yourself or you can loop through the Request.Querystring NameValueCollection:`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Request.QueryString)
    {
       string  a = item.Key; 
        string b = item.Value;

    }
```

You'll know the U stands for the original base url, the other items are the params in the original  url